# Exporting a Resource Dictionary as String

Tags: c#, wpf, export, resourcedictionary

It is possible to export my current resource dictionary as string? I wish I could export a merged dictionary containing all of the strings of the user chooses to translate my app for example.

I know that I can access informations about my app's resources at `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries`. Each dictionary contains a Original string pointing to Resources/Localization/[name].xaml

But how could I access the contents of this resource to export as string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it!

To save a `Resource Dictionary` as a file, I just needed 2 lines of code:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(XamlFileName))
    XamlWriter.Save(Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[6], writer);
```

In my case, I wanted to save only one of my `Resource Dictionary`.

Now, the only issue is that the text file isn't formatted. :/